# Fastest way to update a TListView

Tags: c++builder, tlistview

I have a **TListView** that gets populated with data collected over a network. To collect all the data takes around 50ms, to add it to the list takes around 5 seconds. My initial guess was that it was redrawing after every addition or something like that. What should I do to get the **TListView** to update as quickly as possible?

Columns and items are all added via code.

I tried using *BeginUpdate* and *EndUpdate* on the items of the list but that didn't make much difference. There are around 2000 entries that are added to the list.

Comment: Post the update code, showing your calls to begin/endupdate! And make sure they are *outside* your 1..2000 loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, there is no way to know for sure why your updates are that slow.  However, if speed is an issue for you, especially with a lot of list items, you should put the `TListView` into virtual mode instead (set its `OwnerData` property to true) and store your status information elsewhere, not in the `TListView` itself (2000 items is a lot of overhead for a non-virtual ListView to handle).  Then, simply call the ListView's `Invalidate()` or `UpdateItems()` method when needed to trigger repaints, and use the `OnData` event to provide the status data to `TListView` whenever it asks you for it.  For example:

```
struct MyStatusInfo
{
    String Status;
    ...
};

MyStatusInfo StatusItems[2000];

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    ...
    ListView1->Items->Count = 2000;  // you don't use Add() with a virtual ListView
    ...
}

void __fastcalll TForm1::UpdateStatus(int Index, const String &Status, ...)
{
    MyStatusInfo &Info = StatusItems[Item->Index];
    Info.Status = Status;
    ...
    ListView1->UpdateItems(Index, Index);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1Data(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item)
{
    MyStatusInfo &Info = StatusItems[Item->Index];
    Item->Caption = Info.Status;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea, I read a bit about the virtual ListViews and that felt like the way to go. Either that or write my own ListView. I'll have to look more closely at the code though since it does access the data/objects quite a bit.

Comment: I use a virtual `TListView` to display up to millions of items at one time, and the performance is very good, especially when using the `OnDataHint` event to optimize memory usage so all of the items do not need to be allocated in memory at one time. My ListView usage only takes up about 15-20 MB of memory, though my overall data could be up to multiple GBs of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that helps, since BeginUpdate didn't, but it worth trying:

1) Try filling it while Enabled = false, then enable it

2) Try building a TListItems and assign it directly to the TListView's Items properties